# how to do not allow particular user to give rating using ratyrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ratyrate gem for rating in my rails application.
there is user who can purchase or sell his books.
but User can not rate his own book(Uploaded by same user).

and when i reload page then only it show rating.
how to show rating on button click without reload.....

User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rater
end
```

Book model.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  ratyrate_rateable "price_for_sale"
end
```

books/index.html.erb.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <table class="cls_book_details" cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0">  
        <tr>
            <%@count =1 %>
            <% @books.each do |book| %>
                <td id="book_details" style="text align:left;"><%=link_to(image_tag(book.book_photos.first.photo.url(:thumb), :title => 'Click for edit'), edit_book_path(book.id))%><br>
                    Book Title : <%= book.book_name %><br>
                    Author : <%= book.book_auther %><br>
                    <%= rating_for book, "price_for_sale", :enable_half => true %><br/><br>
                    </td>
                <%@count += 1 %>
                <%if @count == 4%>
                    <% @count =1 %>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                <%end %>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste some code that you did.

Comment: Not getting you by your comment. will you elaborate?

Comment: When you click on rate start to give rating. please paste that log. which action and controller is being execute.

Comment: ignore comment.
below i mention I want to restrict user to can not give rating to his books, he can only see rating

Comment: Let me create a room where I can help you out

Comment: Processing by RaterController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"score"=>"1.3271484375", "dimension"=>"price_for_sale", "id"=>"250", "klass"=>"Book"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73298/discussion-between-ssr-and-ashvin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you should check your logged in user with your book user. If they are same then prevent him by doing so

```
if obj.user.id == current_user.id
  flash[:alert] = "You can not rate your own book"
else
  obj.rate params[:score].to_f, current_user, params[:dimension]
end
```

Your second question's answer is use ajax not to reload page.

Full detail over AJAX in rails http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Here is an good example
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3--net-15243